# What redirect uri to use on Cordova with the Deezer Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth-2.0, redirect, deezer

I am working on a mobile application, using Cordova. I want to implement the Deezer Javascript SDK. Everything is fine except for one thing: I cannot implement the login method (DZ.login).

DZ.login method uses the oauth2 protocol. When I call it, I access the Deezer connection interface, so I can write my credentials. But it comes to redirection, I only get a white screen.

The fact is that I don't know, and I did not find what redirect_url to use.
Indeed, when you register an application on Deezer Developers, you have to give an application domain, and a redirect uri. I tried lots:

- localhost / http: //localhost/index.html (Gives me a white screen)
- com.company.app / http: //app.company.com/index.html (Gives me an invalid redirect uri)
- company / "http: //company.com/index.html" (Gives me an invalid redirect uri)
  (I put spaces between http: and // as my reputation is not high enough to post more than 2 links)

This is the SDK initialization function:

```
initDeezerSDK: function() {
    DZ.init({
        appId  : 'myAppId',
        channelUrl : 'http://localhost/channel.html',
        player: {
            onload: function () {
                alert("yo");
            }
        }
    });
    },
```

This is the Deezer login function:

```
DZ.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                DZ.api('/user/me', function(response) {
                    $('deezer-name').val(response.name);
                    window.location.href = '#profile';
                    alert(response.name);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        },
        {
            perms: 'basic_access,email'
        });
```

Thanks for your help guys, this part is really critical for my app... Cheers!

[Deezer developers interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7XjU.png)

Comment: Normally, you only have to declare a proper domain on your application settings on developers.deezer.com, and allow a redirect_uri to this specific domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fact is that I don't know what domain to declare. Does my application need to be hosted on a server with a domain name ?

Comment: you can just set "localhost" if you want and are working on your dev environment, but you have to declare it and to mention it in the redirect_uri if you want to use the login feature.

Comment: Excuse-me if I misunderstand, but as I said in my post, setting localhost as my app domain, and http://localhost/index.html as my redirect_uri just gives me a white screen. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Your settings seem OK, so you should more investigate about the redirection to you index.html, if it works correctly or not